# Google Drive v2 API , issues with nextLink and pagetoken

Tags: c++, rest, google-drive-api

just in case if someone here might know about this

I am implementing this with c++ in Windows environment

this is the url I received in earlier file listing, I did cut the tokens away to keep it shorter ,

when I send request like this to network , I only get bad request error 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=20&pageToken=valid_page_token&access_token=valid_access_token>

but when I add underscore _ to change pageToken to page_Token, I get file listing response from google drive .

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=20&page_Token=valid_page_token&access_token=valid_access_token>

So I wonder , which way this should be now, or do I always need to manipulate the string to get following request to be working fine

Comment: pageToken works for me. Are you sure that you are correctly urlencoding the valid_page_token?

Comment: I will check that as well but the actual problem is in parameter pageToken vs. page_Token. I need to replace pageToken by page_Token to get at least some kind of response. Have you faced that ?

Comment: no. it works as advertised for me